# WPF VB Export datagrid (not datagridview) to Excel

Tags: wpf, excel, vb.net

I use VB.NET in WPF. i just knew that it seems WPF datagrid are different from Datagridview, below are usual VB export routine

```
Private Sub BtnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim app As Object
    Dim xlbook As Object
    Dim xlsheet As Object
    app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
    xlsheet = xlbook.ActiveSheet
    app.Visible = True
    Try
        Dim iX As Integer
        Dim iY As Integer
        Dim iC As Integer
        Dim iz As Integer
        For iC = 0 To DGJrn.Columns.Count - 1
            xlsheet.Cells(1, iC + 1).Value = DGJrn.Columns(iC).Header
        Next

        iz = 1
        For iX = 0 To DGJrn.Rows.Count - 1
            For iY = 0 To DGJrn.Columns.Count - 1
                Dim a As String = DGJrn(iY, iX).Value
                If a <> Nothing Then xlsheet.Cells(iz + 1, iY + 1) = (DGJrn(iY, iX).Value & "").ToString()
            Next
            iz = iz + 1
        Next
        app.Visible = True
        app.UserControl = True
        releaseobject(app)
        releaseobject(xlbook)
        releaseobject(xlsheet)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
    AppActivate(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id)
    MsgBox("Data has been successfuly generated!")

End Sub
```

I always fail with "datagrid cannot be indexed" Could you please help?
Edit: Adding xml and binding

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGJrn" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,39" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="JTYPE" Binding="{Binding Path=JType}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="JSRC" Binding="{Binding Path=JSrc}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="TRNDT" Binding="{Binding Path=TrnDt, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Period" Binding="{Binding Path=Period}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Desc" Binding="{Binding Path=Desc}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="TrnRef" Binding="{Binding Path=TrnRef}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="AccCode" Binding="{Binding Path=AccCode}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="BASum" Binding="{Binding Path=BASum}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DbtCrd" Binding="{Binding Path=DbtCrd}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="OtAmt" Binding="{Binding Path=OtAmt}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="T1" Binding="{Binding Path=T1}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="T2" Binding="{Binding Path=T2}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="T3" Binding="{Binding Path=T3}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="T4" Binding="{Binding Path=T4}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="T5" Binding="{Binding Path=T5}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="T6" Binding="{Binding Path=T6}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="T7" Binding="{Binding Path=T7}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="T8" Binding="{Binding Path=T8}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Remrk" Binding="{Binding Path=Remrk}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Connection:

```
Private Sub LoadGrid()
    Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DT As New System.Data.DataTable
    Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand

    With ConAccess
        Try
            If .State = ConnectionState.Open Then .Close()
            .Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error Connection : " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End With
    Dim Sql As String = ""
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM APJI;"

    Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Sql, ConAccess)
    DA.SelectCommand = Cmd
    DA.Fill(DT)

    DGJrn.ItemsSource = DT.DefaultView

End Sub
```

Comment: The source of the error is probably `DGJrn(iY, iX)`. The solution depends on your actual data. Is your datagrid bound to some items collection or what is the source of what is displayed? You are better of creating the export from the same datasource as your view instead of trying to create the export from the view itself. Generally speaking, a single cell inside the WPF DataGrid could contain an entire sub-application (though thats not the typical usage), so good luck deriving some primitive export value from that.

Comment: I strongly recommend saving the `DataTable DT` somewhere and writing the export based on that one instead of the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Hi grek.. i got your point, i will try to find a way to export from DataTable instead. thank you for you comments

Answer (score 0):

need to close my own question, so i need to change the source from DataGrid to DataTable instead. so this is my code now:

```
Private Sub DatatableToExcel()
    Dim _excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    wBook = _excel.Workbooks.Add()
    wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()

    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = Dtab
    Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
    Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
    Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

    For Each dc In dt.Columns
        colIndex = colIndex + 1
        _excel.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
    Next

    For Each dr In dt.Rows
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        colIndex = 0
        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            _excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
        Next
    Next

    wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
    Dim strFileName As String = "C:\datatable.xlsx"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName)
    End If

    wBook.SaveAs(strFileName)
    wBook.Close()
    _excel.Quit()
End Sub
```